# Trying to mock Laravel Facade with MyFacade::shouldReceive() results in "cannot redeclare shouldReceive()"

Tags: php, mocking, laravel-8, laravel-facade

On Laravel 8, I've created a facade and registered the service provider in Laravel. In my Pest test I've added `\App\Facades\Twilio::shouldReceive('AsAdmin');`.

Running the test results in:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Mockery_2_App_Facades_Twilio::shouldReceive() in /app/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(34) : eval()'d code on line 1032
```

There's nothing special in my Facade:

```php
class Twilio extends Facade
{
    protected Client $adminCli;
    protected PendingRequest $http;

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'twilio'; // same as bind method in service provider
    }

    public function AsAdmin()
    {
        $username = config('twilio.account_sid');
        $password = config('twilio.auth_token');

        $this->adminCli = new Client($username, $password);

        $this->http = Http::withBasicAuth($username, $password);

        return $this;
    }
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a circular reference to the Twilio facade.

The `getFacadeAccessor()` instructs the Facade on which service to use.

```php
# Twilio Facade

protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'twilio'; // same as bind method in service provider
}
```

In my Twilio service provider I had the following, which calls back to the Facade that is calling the service provider. The service provider needs to provide access to a service (SDK for example), not the facade.

```php
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('twilio',function(){
            # Wrong:
            #   return new \App\Facades\Twilio();
          
            # Correct:
            return new \Twilio\Rest\Client(config('twilio.username'), config('twilio.password')
        });
    }
```